# countIf with merged cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Given this sheet, I'd like to count duplicates in column B:

```
[ ][  A  ][  B  ][  C  ][  D  ]
[1][     cat    ][     ][     ]
[2][     ][ cat ][     ][ dog ]
[3][        cat        ][ bar ]
[4][     ][ hat ][     ][     ]
[5][     ][     cat    ][ red ]
[6][            cat           ]
[7][     ][ mad ][     ][     ]
[8][ cat ][ cat ][     ][ cat ]
```

If I use `=countif(B1:B7,"cat")` Google Sheets only counts cells `B2`, `B5`, and `B8`, and it doesn't count `B1`, `B3`, and `B6`.

Note that I didn't want to count cells `A8` and `D8`, as I specifically only want to count duplicates in column B.

Comment: Yes nice table, but to answer your question: the issue is that there are no values in B1,B3 and B6.  The value resides in Column A and as such a formula will not work here.  This is the problem with using Merged Cells on anything but the final output.  Formulas cannot determine if a cell is merged or not.

Comment: Is there a workaround without using apps script?

Comment: No.  We could count both A and B and subtract where both(see line 8), but what if there is no value in B and it is not merged, how is the formula supposed to know to skip that one.  The only way is with script.

Answer (score 0):

Excel considers that the value in a merged cell is actually contained in the first (most left) cell of the merged cells.

I can think only of one method to accomplish this with formulas, but it requires manual  formatting of the merged cells, and a helper column.

You can format the merged cells as numbers with colored negative numbers. As there is text in the cells, this will have no impact on how the text is formatted, but you can still extract with `CELL("color", A1)` the formatting (`1` if formatted to be red for negative numbers, and `0` otherwise).

In the helper column you copy the value from column B if the cell is not "colored", or from column A if "colored". Probably you also could accomplish this with an array formula and without using a helper column.

Anyway, it does require you to first (manually) format the merged cells (using format painter this obviously is very fast and easy if the number of rows is a *reasonable* number.